# Counter example to the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations

Tags: examples-counterexamples, calculus-of-variations

This is the counter example which my teacher gave
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin x \sin 2x\:dx=0$$
I tried to disprove him, but I couldn't suceed. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: For the Lemma to hold, it must be true that $\int_D f(x)h(x)\, dx = 0$ for *all* smooth compactly supported $h$.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Does the question not satisfy the conditions of the lemma?

Comment: How is this a counter example?

Comment: @Hagen please tell me why it is not, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @GurumayumMadan a) what is the precise statement that this is a counter-example of? b) For a statement of the form $P\to Q$ to have a counterexmple, we need an instance where $P$, but not $Q$, so when **you** present this as a counterexample, you better have arguments that suggest that $P$ holds and $Q$ does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you give me a continuous function $f$ and ask me if it is identically zero. The fundamental Lemma of calculus of variations tells me that if I take *every* smooth compactly support function $h$ and show that

$$
\int_D f(x)h(x) \, dx = 0
$$

Then I can conclude $f \equiv 0$. However, what you have done is simply show that for *one particular* $h$

$$
\int_D f(x)h(x) \, dx = 0
$$

If I take a different $h$, say $h := f$, you will find integral is nonzero. Therefore, $f \not\equiv 0$.

Comment: Does sin2x not satisfy the smooth compactly supported condition?

Comment: $\sin(2x)$ is smooth and compactly supported. However, you have not tested *every* function $h$, just one. To use the Lemma, you must test *every* smooth compactly supported function: $x$, $e^x$, $\sin(\sin(\sin(e^{10x})))$, $\sin(2x)$, ...

Comment: $h(x)=0$ also satisfies the smooth compactly supported conditio n...

Comment: So the catch here is to identify "For EVERY...compact....functions" right? So, only one function cannot insure the demotion of the lemma, right?

Comment: Exactly. If you were to come up with a counter example. You would need to find a continuous nonzero function $f$ such that for *every* compact smoothly supported $h$ the integral is $0$. No such counterexample exists because the Lemma has been proven.

Answer (score 1):

Let us base our argument on the formulation of the lemma in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations):

> If a continuous function $f$ on an open interval $( a , b )$ satisfies the equality
>   $$\tag1\int _{a}^{b}f(x)h(x)\,\mathrm {d} x=0$$
>      for all compactly supported smooth functions $h$ on $( a , b )$, then $f$ is identically zero.

So in order to present a counter-example (if such existed), we'd have to

- specify an open interval $(a,b)$,
- specify a continuous function $f$ on $(a,b)$,
- show that for all compactly supported smooth functions $h$ on $(a,b)$ equation $(1)$ holds,
- and show that  $f$ is not identically zero.

Instead, you merely present a single equation of the form $\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$.
Even when using a crystal ball to interprete that, the closest to a counterexample is that you want $a=0$, $b=2\pi$, $f(x)=\sin x$ (which at least is non-zero), and have verified equation $(1)$ for a single specific case, namely $h(x)=\sin 2x$. However, to qualify as a counterexample this would have to be shown for all allowed choices of $h$.

Abstractly, a counterexmple to a statement of the form $\forall f\colon \Phi(f)$ is a specific $f$ for which $\neg\Phi(f)$ (which thus proves $\exists f\colon \neg \Phi(f)$, the negation of $\forall f\colon \Phi(f)$). Here $\Phi(f)$ is itself of the form $(\forall h\colon \Psi(f,h))\to \Theta(f)$, so $\neg\Phi(f)$ is $(\forall h\colon \Psi(f,h))\land\neg \Theta(f)$; it seems you supposed that $\neg\Phi(f)$ were $(\neg\forall h\colon \Psi(f,h))\to \Theta(f)$ (or equivalently $(\exists h\colon \neg\Psi(f,h))\to \Theta(f)$).